# How to map multiple tables to one table using one to one relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I have following classes

```
   Class A ()
    {
      public virtual ThisClass  thisClass { get; set; }
    }

     Class B ()
    {
      public virtual ThisClass thisClass { get; set; }
    }

    Class C ()
    {
      public virtual ThisClass thisClass { get; set; }
    }

     Class D ()
    {
      public virtual ThisOne thisClass { get; set; }
    }


// 

    Class ThisClass 
   { 
      [ForeignKey("A")]
      [ForeignKey("B")]
      [ForeignKey("C")]
      [ForeignKey("D")]
      Public int Id {get;set;}

   }
```

I don't know how can assign those foreign keys using entity framework, what are the ways for that ?

Site needs more words from me so I am writing this line, kindly ignore this one. thanks

Comment: I'm counting 5 classes, not 3.

Comment: Sorry, that was typo

Comment: Still, can you suggest me the solution to it? @Marco

Answer (score 0):

Your class would be like :

```
 Class ThisClass 
 {       
   Public int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual A  a { get; set; }
   public virtual B  b { get; set; }
   public virtual C  c { get; set; }
   public virtual D  d{ get; set; }
 }
```

One to one mapping can be done like this way using fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<A >()
    .HasKey(e => e.Id );
    modelBuilder.Entity<B >()
    .HasKey(e => e.Id );
    modelBuilder.Entity<C >()
    .HasKey(e => e.Id );
    modelBuilder.Entity<D >()
    .HasKey(e => e.Id );




    modelBuilder.Entity<ThisClass >()
            .HasRequired(s => s.A) 
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.thisClass); 

    modelBuilder.Entity<ThisClass >()
            .HasRequired(s => s.B) 
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.thisClass); 


    modelBuilder.Entity<ThisClass >()
            .HasRequired(s => s.C) 
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.thisClass); 

    modelBuilder.Entity<ThisClass >()
            .HasRequired(s => s.D) 
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.thisClass); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ans but it gave me and error "The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names."

Comment: Try by replacing HasRequired(s => s.A)  'A' to small 'a' as the property name is a. same for rest of all.

Comment: you can get more help from here ..http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Yes, I knew that one, I changed certain things which I thought which could be problematic  but still it doesn't work " One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:"

Comment: For one it works fine but when I try to do it multiple then it fails

Comment: I tried that link , which is almost opposite to what you suggested, but still at the time of insertion it gives error. With your code it was giving an error at the time of migration